# Isolated Triac Driving on Low RMS Current Load

Tags: ac, power-electronics, opto-isolator, triac, contactor

I'm trying to drive a triac to control contactors. Here is the circuit I'm using:
[image]

I have 3 different contactors which has series resistances like: 200R, 550R, 1.4k

When using contactors with 200R and 550R resistance, there is no problem, the driving circuit works fine. When I try to use the contactor with 1.4k resistor, circuit pulls the contactor but never release it, so it's not working properly with contactor with high resistance.

I've found an application note AN-4993 from ST indicates that "this circuit is not able to drive low rms current loads", which is same as my situation.
Here is AN-4993: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/b1/6f/59/1d/45/f1/4f/30/DM00356324/files/DM00356324.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00356324.pdf

What's the reason behind this, why is this driving circuit not working with high resistance(low current) contactors?

My optotriac is MOC3021, main triac is BTA12, R1=tried many from 50R to 3k, R2=tried 100R to 350R, C1 is 100nF.

PS: When I reduce the C1 value to 50nF, it solve the problem but turn on spike started to happen on triac so the 100nF is a proper value for protecting triac from turn on issues.

Comment: Curret throught the load is so small, that capacitor is unable uo fully charge, so there is no enough energy to turn on the triac.

Comment: Probably due to the inductive nature of contactor, the triac can re-trigger if there is no snubber circuit. Add a  RC snubber.

Comment: Also, a BTA12 is not suitable for switching mA currents, since it has relatively high holding current. For small loads you have also to use small signal triacs.